# Component Not Rendering React - Using Older React Router Dom Version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom

Hey guys using an older version of react-router-dom because I had to for this input form github i forked.  Used to using useNavigate but this version is useHistory.  I want to go from my main. dashboard to a page called House.js which renders a component MakePost.js. Whenever i travel to House its just a blank white screen. No errors. Help

Here is my **Dashboard.js**

```
  async function House(){
    return(history.push('/House'))
  }

  return (
    <><>
      <h2 className="title" style={{ left: "20%", marginTop: -150, marginLeft: 30 }}>Lestinsky Auctions.</h2>
    </><>

        <Card style={{ width: '400px', height: '500px', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Card.Body>
            <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Profile</h2>
            {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
            <strong>Email:</strong> {currentUser.email}
            <Link to="/update-profile" className="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-3">
              Update Profile
            </Link>
            <div>
              <Button onClick={House} className="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-3">Go To Auction House</Button>
            </div>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
        <div style={{ left: '100%' }} className="w-100 text-center mt-2 btn btn-secondary">
          <Link className="w-100 text-center mt-2 btn btn-secondary" variant="link" onClick={handleLogout}>
            Log Out
          </Link>
        </div>


      </></>
  )
```

Here is my **MakePost.js**

```
import React, { useState} from 'react'
import { storage } from '../firebase'
import { ref, uploadBytes } from 'firebase/firebase-storage-compat'
import { v4 } from 'uuid'

function Upload(){
    const [imageUpload, setImageUpload] = useState(null)
    const uploadImage = () => {
        if(imageUpload == null) return;
        const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${imageUpload.name + v4 }`)
        uploadBytes(imageRef, imageUpload).then(() => {
            alert("Image Uploaded")
        })

    }


    return(
        <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={(event) => {setImageUpload(event.target.files)}}>
            <button onClick={uploadImage}></button>
            </input>
        </div>
    )

}


export default Upload
```

and here is my **House.js**

```
import MakePost from './MakePost'

function House(){
    return(
        <MakePost></MakePost>
    )
}

export default House
```

Comment: can you please the file that contains your project routes

Comment: return(history.push('/House')) <- seems wrong to me. Should the House function be:
function House(){
    history.push('/House')
}

Comment: What specific versions of `react` and `react-router-dom` are installed? You can check by running `npm list react react-router-dom` in the terminal in the root project directory. Are you rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component? Can you edit the post to include ***all*** relevant code as part of your [mcve] (*i.e. the router, routes, etc...*)?